# How to rank sql results by foreign key matches

Tags: php, mysql

How can I rank results based on the most matched foreign key id's?

eg:

```
$tag_ids = '1, 2, 3';

$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM `posts` p 
LEFT JOIN `tags_posts` tp 
ON tp.`post_id` = p.`id`
WHERE
tp.`tag_id` IN (". $tag_ids .")";
```

Tables: `posts`, `tags`, `tags_posts` (join table)

One post can have many tags

One tag can belong to many posts

How can I rank posts that have the most matched tag ids from the one's that are given ($tag_ids)

EDIT:

```
I need to use this in a larger UNION query

$sql_1 = "SELECT `id`, `date`, ... FROM `first_table` ... LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY `first_table`.`id`";

$sql_2 = "SELECT `id`, `date`, ... FROM `second_table` ... LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY `second_table`.`id`";

$sql_3 = "SELECT `id`, `date`, ... FROM `third_table` ... LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY `third_table`.`id`";

$sql = " SELECT * FROM ( 
" . $sql_1 . "
UNION
" . $sql_2 . "
UNION
" . $sql_3 . "
) as t
ORDER BY t.`date` DESC
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by tag_id, then count each group. Largest count is the most matches.

Comment: Can you show me what it would look like. I am already using group by on post_id and this will be part of a larger union query.

Comment: You can group by multiple columns in MySQL with the syntax `GROUP BY col1, col2, col3`. I would probably not even try to get the ranks during the query process if your query is that complex, though. Loop through your results and do your tag counting logic in php.

Comment: So I should get the number of matched foreign keys as a value in the result and handle sorting it outside SQL. sounds good - but how can I get that value?